# Как модель получает данные от сервиса?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, mvc, архитектура, javascript

Ещё ни разу я не разбирал mvc на примере работы с сервером и, начав строить его, столкнулся с проблемой.
Я нажимаю на кнопку и тем самым запускаю цепь сообщений с сервера, которые мне нужно отобразить, но предварительно обработать и сохранить полученные данные в модели.
То есть получается так - сервер шлет сообщение-данные, которые я каким-то образом получаю в модели. Модель парсит данные, заносит их в коллекцию valueObjects и выставляет этот valueObject в качестве currentValueObject, после чего диспатчит событие в вид. Вид ловит событие и считывает нужную информацию с модели, и если что-то нужно поменять в currentValueObject, то делает это через контроллер. Это я не описываю логику, а объясняю, какое у меня видение mvc. Вот.
Но вот, как эти данные с сервера поступят в модель, я не понимаю. Объясните, пожалуйста.

**Дополнение:**
Немного продолжу на примере миниатюры - инитится конфиг приложения, в котором создается модель, вью, в которую передается модель и контроллер, в который передаются и модель и вью. И вот как и в каком месте нужно завязать сервер, чтобы пришедшие от него данные попали в модель?

**Дополнение:**
Пользователь взаимодействует с приложением через вью. События мышки или клавиатуры ловит вью. Зачем контроллер должен обрабатывать эти нажатия? Я нажал на картинку, и вью поймала клик, она включила анимацию взрыва и все. По Вашему сценарию, вью должна передать событие клика в контроллер, который включит анимацию. Но зачем? Разве вью сама не может решить, что она должна показать пользователю? Ведь от картинки логика приложения не изменится. Вью может показать взрыв квадратиками или кружочками, и от этого ничего не изменится. Зачем в это действие понапрасну вовлекать контроллер? Вот если бы я ткнул на кнопку "купить товар", то вью была бы обязанна уведомить о клике контроллер, который вызвал бы метод в модели, которая бы проверила, а есть ли у меня деньги на счету, чтобы этот тавар положить в корзину. После того, как модель бы убедиласть в наличии денег, то диспачнула бы событие, чтобы вью это отобразила. Понимаете, она бы просто диспачнула, а не диспачнула конкретно кому-то. А нужная вью бы подхватила и отобразила товар в корзине так, как ей бы это хотелось. Пока действие во вью не затрагивают логику приложения, вью обрабатывает все сама. Как только от действий вью начинает зависить состояние всего приложения, то вью диспатчит событие контроллеру, а тот дергает методы в модели, а она диспатчит вью, и если того требуется, то вью лезет и берет нужные данные из модели по отведенным ей интерфейсом геттерам.
А в Вашем случае - вью ничего не обрабатывает, она диспатчит контроллеру, который выбирает, что и когда вью будет показывать. Контроллер использует и приказывает модели, как хранилищу. Видите? У Вас контроллер вобрал в себя всю бизнес логику, и именно поэтому GoF назвали такой контроллер жирный и уродливый. Но если углубляться, то существует намного больше типов моделей, чем просто модель, и именно из-за них у d' разработчиков возникают сложности с понятием.

**Дополнение:**
Чтобы ещё больше подтвердить, что я Вас понимаю, я спрошу на конкретном примере, который я сейчас делаю.
Нажал я кнопку сохранить на клавиатуре, и сработало событие nodejs, которое начинает передавать поток данных о файлах из указанной директории...

Это было небольшое вступление, но сейчас я вернусь назад во времени и попытаюсь прокомментировать инициализацию...
Чтобы отбросить споры о МЕСТЕ инициализации, я не буду его называть, и начнем просто с того, что файловая система является неким подобием сервера, а значит данные, которые nodejs мне отправляет, можно сравнить с данными, пришедшими с сервера. Я прав?

Comment: > Но вот как эти данные с сервера поступят в модель я не понимаю.
> **после чего диспатчит событие в вид. **

этим занимается контроллер. mvc же у вас или я ошибся ?

Comment: Нет, я говорю о просто контроллере. Вам поспорить или понять хочется? В вашем объяснении MVC слова "контроллер" вообще нет. В этом и проблема понимания. Насчет толстых контроллеров и глупой модели вот этот пример - сильно глупая модель?

     var friendsOfFriend=user.getFriends(otherUser);


прочитайте примеры php из той-же статьи, видите там **`$this->render('create'....)`**? Что это такое по-вашему?

В активной модели именно контроллер подписывает представление на модель. [Пример](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub/subscribe.html?q=example-usage
).

Comment: Ещё раз - чем, по-вашему, контроллер вообще занимается? Зачем вообще C в MVC? Я вам пытаюсь донести простую вещь - как обрабатывать данные от юзера решает контроллер (решает так - преобразовывает запрос от юзера в вызов модели), он же решает, подписать ли представление на событие модели или нет, и как именно подписывать. Или у вас модель может ещё и авторизацией сама занимается? В общем, тонкость контроллера не подразумевает его отсутствие.

> Однако модель не зависит ни от представления, ни от контроллера.

Т.е. модель не знает, как её данные будут визуализированы.

Comment: > Разве вью сама не может решить, что она должна показать пользователю?

Нет. Пользователь посылает запрос, контроллер его разруливает, конкретное представление, выбранное контроллером, показывает то, что запрограммировано показывать. Представление не решает ничего.

Comment: @vas, толстые и уродливые контроллеры получаются обычно в том случае, если в экшен запихнули несколько (обычный запрос, аякс, еще что-нибудь) и при недостатке абстракции. Они совсем не из-за парадигмы толстыми получаются.

Comment: > В свою очередь, контроллеры представляют собой лишь элементы системы, в чьи непосредственные обязанности входит приём данных из запроса и передача их **другим элементам системы**.

@vas Почему у вас вызов представления вдруг стал бизнес логикой мне непонятно. Модель она не в курсе кто ее куда зачем подписал, ее задача дернуть событие в соответствии с АПИ , она не в курсе дернет она просто callback контроллера или её данные отправятся непосредственно представлению. Так вот - что именно произойдет с данными что от пользователя что от модели решает контроллер, даже если он решает это подпиской

Comment: @vas теперь я попрошу вас согласиться с одним утверждением: я не тупой и я знаю, про что говорю.

> В этом случае модель выступает исключительно совокупностью функций для доступа к данным, а контроллер содержит бизнес-логику

и за счет этого раздувается - за счет того, что методы, которые должны быть вынесены в модель или компоненты, валяются прямо в контроллере. **О чем я и говорил выше**.

> модель — это не только совокупность кода доступа к данным и СУБД, но и вся бизнес-логика

Нормальный контроллер - это:

    результат = модель.выполнить_логику()
    вызвать_вью(результат)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте, чтобы вы перестали отсылать нас в википедию, я просто прокомментирую статью.

---

> Основная **цель** применения этой концепции состоит **в разделении бизнес-логики** (модели) **от** её **визуализации** (представления, вида).

Т.е. утверждая, что модель управляет представлением, вы отвергаете основную цель концепции.

> Концепция MVC позволяет разделить данные, представление и обработку действий пользователя на три отдельных компонента:
>
> Модель (англ. Model). Модель предоставляет знания: данные и методы работы с этими данными, реагирует на запросы, изменяя своё состояние. **Не содержит информации, как эти знания можно визуализировать**.

Т.е. модель может пополнить самостоятельно баланс, вызвать стороннее API, сложить данные для нотификации юзера и т.д. (в том числе сложить в поток подписки).

> Представление, вид (англ. View). Отвечает за отображение информации (визуализацию). Часто в качестве представления выступает форма (окно) с графическими элементами.

Про это чуть ниже.

> Контроллер (англ. Controller). Обеспечивает связь между пользователем и системой: контролирует ввод данных пользователем и использует **модель** и **представление** для реализации необходимой реакции.

Модель **И** представление

> Важно отметить, что как представление, так и контроллер зависят от модели. Однако **модель не зависит ни от представления, ни от контроллера**. Тем самым достигается назначение такого разделения: оно позволяет строить модель независимо от визуального представления, **а также создавать несколько различных представлений для одной модели**.

Модель предоставляет унифицированные интерфейсы, контроллер вызывает методы модели, модель реагирует. Реакции модели могут быть самыми разнообразными. Мало того, выше особо указано, что представления для одной модели могут быть разными.

> Для реализации схемы Model-View-Controller используется достаточно большое число шаблонов проектирования (в зависимости от сложности архитектурного решения), основные из которых «наблюдатель», «стратегия», «компоновщик»[5].
> Наиболее типичная реализация **отделяет вид от модели** путем установления между ними **протокола взаимодействия**, используя аппарат событий (подписка/оповещение).

Этот протокол называется API.

> При каждом изменении внутренних данных в модели она оповещает все зависящие от неё представления, и представление обновляется. Для этого используется шаблон «наблюдатель». При обработке реакции пользователя **вид выбирает**, в зависимости от нужной реакции, **нужный контроллер**, который **обеспечит** ту или иную **связь с моделью**.

Контроллер обеспечивает связь - не модель.

> Для этого используется шаблон «стратегия», или вместо этого может быть модификация с использованием шаблона «команда». А для возможности однотипного обращения с подобъектами сложно-составного иерархического вида может использоваться шаблон «компоновщик». Кроме того, могут использоваться и другие шаблоны проектирования, например, «фабричный метод», который позволит задать по умолчанию тип контроллера для соответствующего вида.

---

> > Среднестатистический ТТУК получал данные из БД (используя уровень абстракции базы данных, делая вид, что это модель) или манипулировал, проверял, записывал, а также передавал данные в Представление. Такой подход стал очень популярен потому, что использование таких контроллеров похоже на классическую практику использования отдельного php-файла для каждой страницы приложения

Тут не очень понятно, частично абзац противоречит остальной статье. Но автор абзаца не понял, почему это происходило в php, в php в общем-то невозможны подписки представлений (или это очень сложно и ведет к гигантским дырам в самой концепции MVC, например, представление будет вынуждено обращаться к модели напрямую), в силу особенности его использования (запуск->обработка->выход).

> Но в объектно-ориентированном программировании используется активная модель MVC, где модель — это не только совокупность кода доступа к данным и СУБД, но и вся бизнес-логика. Следует отметить возможность модели инкапсулировать в себе другие модели. В свою очередь, контроллеры представляют собой лишь элементы системы, в чьи **непосредственные обязанности** входит **приём данных из запроса** и **передача** их **другим элементам** системы. Только в этом случае контроллер становится «тонким» и выполняет исключительно функцию связующего звена (glue layer) между отдельными компонентами системы.

Другие элементы - это модели и представления (каких-либо ещё элементов в концепции просто нет).

---

Автор [статьи](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2008/12/the-m-in-mvc-why-models-are-misunderstood-and-unappreciated/), на которую ссылается вики, напрямую говорит, что лучший контроллер - это отсутствующий контроллер. В таком случае концепт, который он продвигает, называется [MVVM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-ViewModel).

Comment: @vas, ей-богу, оставьте поиск смысла в порядке букв Задорнову.

Comment: @vas все неправы, а я прав.

> Понимаете, я не хочу из-за Вашего неоспаримого опыта, принимать Ваш НЕПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ взгляд на MVC. 

Найдите здесь хоть один комментарий без обоснования, что-нибудь типа "ну сколько ни делал, а мне всё норм".

> Если Вы скажите, что все, кто делает фраймворки тоже ошибаются... ДА! Они тоже все ошибаются, так-как не спорят, а делают и раз у них получается, это дает им право выкладывать код в массы, а массам пользоваться им.

WAT

> неоспаримого  
> фраймворк
> Если вы скажите

адище короч.

Comment: @vas парадигмам абсолютно без разницы, в каком языке существовать. И да, в js полно mvc-фреймворков.

> И указанные ошибки, это минус Вам, а не мне!

Какие ошибки?

> Но только то в том и дело, что все у Вас делает контроллер - он и решает, что вид будет показывать и что и когда модель будет делать.

В идеале, как я выше писал - да, всего две строчки, тернарник еще может какой для выбора представления в зависимости от результата.

Comment: @vas, смотря что за сервис. Например, если это сервис распечатки и высылки по почте открыток hello kitty или управление системой наведения катапульты, то конечно может. Если же сервис это часть приложения... в общем комбайны тоже зло :) Если же под сервисом вы понимаете helper... тут разные мнения, я не копал глубоко, но ходят слухи, что CI на этом погорел.

Comment: В общем я так и не уловил той нотки, ради которой и задал вопрос. По этому я создам новую тему, а здесь помещу пригласительную ссылку на неё. Чтобы все на конкретном примере.

Comment: Прошу все проследовать по этой ссылке :) http://hashcode.ru/questions/357173/javascript-пример-mvc-сервера